# No Error Message in Console during Call function in PysimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

I want to use PySimpleGUI to create a basic GUI, that takes a value as input, and if a button is pressed, a function should start with the input text as parameter. The problem is that the GUI crashes and no errors are printed, so I cant understand whats the issue. Even if I use print("something"), nothing appears in the console.
I tried by replacing the function with a simple add() function, and the GUI still crashes. What am I doing wrong? I put the code below, with the simple function instead of the original one.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
def add(x):
    return x+3
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [  
            [sg.Text('Enter the sentence'), sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')],
            [sg.Button('Translate'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
            [sg.Text(""), sg.Output(key='OUTPUT') ]
            ]
window = sg.Window('AAC', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'Translate':
        v = values['-INPUT-']
        window['OUTPUT'].update(add(v))
window.close()
```

If I could see the errors maybe I would understand, but nothing is output, the gui just crashes.
Thank you.

EDIT: I just understood that here the problem is fixed by adding int() to the function parameter. But still, I would like to get the error in the console, so that I could understand whats the problem of more complex function.

Comment: The value of an Input element is a string, not integer and float, so you cannot add it with another integer.

Comment: @JasonYang can you see the edit please?

Comment: How did you run the script ? It's better to run it by `python myscript.py` in console.

Comment: @JasonYang Yes I did and its the same behaviour as if I run it in the IDE, not showing errors, just closing the window and the script ends.

Comment: It's caused by the `Output` element, it will redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to Output element and GUI closed when exception happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the exception as

```py
d:\>python test4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\test4.py", line 21, in <module>
    window['OUTPUT'].update(add(v))
  File "d:\test4.py", line 4, in add
    return x+3
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

The type of value for an Input element is `str`, you cannot add it with another integer. Convert it into `int` or `float` before you add it with a number.

```py
def add(x):
    return int(x) + 3
```

Replace `Output` element by `Multiline` element, or the information of the exception won't be shown on console.

`Output` element is a sub-class of `Multiline` element, with options `reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True`, then all outputs on `stdout` and `stderr` will be transferred to and shown on the `Output` element. Now GUI closed for the exception, so you will get nothing about it.

Comment: Wow!  That's a gotcha.